# No relation between branches after using svn2git

Tags: git, git-svn

I have converted a SVN project to git using svn2git.
Everything went o.k. except there is no relation between the branches. Each branch starts with the same commits (same SHA1 hash value as the master up to the point, where the branch takes its own commits).

This is how it schould look like:

```
master branch1  branch2   
  |       |       |
  |       |       |
  |       |-------'
  |       |  
  |-------'
  |
  |
  |
```

This is how it looks right now:

```
master branch1  branch2   
  |       |       |
  |       |       |
  |       |       |
  |       |       |
  |       |       |
  |       |       |        (same commit hash)
  |       |       |        (same commit hash)
  |       |       |        (same commit hash)
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Stefan

Comment: That’s not possible – if two branches contain the same commit, they are not separate. Why do you think the situation looks like your second drawing?

Comment: sorry, you are right. I am really a newbie on GIT. I was using the git log command wrong. Forgot to add the  --all

Comment: try running this:  `git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate --date-order`

Comment: thank you Chronial. This is even better than the one, I was using now: 'git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph --color'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my mistake. I used `git log` the wrong way.

Forgot to add the `--all` option to show me all the branches at once.